can anyone tell me how can I create multiple objects using vector without specifying the length of vector
I tried to do it using the vector<string> and iterating through it to create the object but while assigning them value i am getting error


#include <iostream> 
#include <string>   
#include <vector>   

class Student {
public:
    std::string name;
    int rollno;
    void display(){
        std::cout << "Name of student is "<<name<< "\nHis Roll Number is " << rollno << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Student> students(10); 
    for (int i = 0;i <10;i++){
        std::string temp;
        std::cout << "Enter name for student " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        std::cin >> temp;
        students[i].name = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x;
        std::cout <<"Enter roll number for student "<<(i + 1)<<": ";
        std::cin>>x;
        students[i].rollno=x;
    }

    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        students[i].display();
    }

    return 0;
}


Edit : All that I want ask is if there is any way to take input from user then make an object with same input as name and store that name in vector<Student> and use this vector to iterate through the list of objects

What do you think Student obj_name[i] does? This declares a new array of Student named obj_name, the size of this array is i (variable-length arrays aren't part of standard C++, but many compilers allow it as an extension).

obj_name[i] is a string, not a Student. So what do you expect obj_name[i].rollno to be?

The Student obj_name[i] arrays you're creating in the 2nd for loop are local to that loop, they go away when the loop ends. In the 3rd loop, obj_name is the std::vector<string> that you declared at the top of main().

You should probably create a vector of students to begin with. During the first loop, create a Student with the given name. Then you can assign to rollno in the 2nd loop (you don't need the middle loop).

never use "#include <bits/stdc++.h>", never use "using namespace std;" We see both mistakes day by day and it will not end... why?

Student obj_name[i]  creates the object of Student class
and I want store the created object into a vector and then use it to give value to class variable and do various operations
how can i do this

You most likely wanted std::vector<Student> Students; instead of  std::vector < string > obj_name;

@drescherjm I tried that but then I can't take object names as input

Why not? Define a constructor for Student that takes the name as a parameter. Then you can do cin >> temp; Student temp_s{temp}; students.push_back(temp_s);

If we're going to recommend a Student constructor (good advice!), might as well take it further and use emplace_back() instead of creating a temporary and push_back().

Here Student temp_s{temp}; students.push_back(temp_s); temp_s is name of the object i want to take name of object
Sorry for not explaining my part i don't want to take the object variable string name;as input instead I want to take name of object which we use when declaring the object as input

i am getting error Which error? Always post the verbatim compiler error

Ok, I knew that the error was due to obj_name[i].rollno = x; I was trying to assign a string who doesn't have any member named rollno
I just wanted to ask if there is any way to take input from user then make an object with same name and store that name in vector<Student> and use this vector to iterate through the list of objects

Do you really want to ask for the name and the rollno for all Students in separate loops instead of asking in 1 loop for all information needed for each individual Student?

I will be getting in put in form of 2 lists first will be list of name and later will be list of rollno so i cant do this all in 1 loop

"#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;" - You lost ~90+% of the knowledgeable people here with just those first two lines of code (and you certainly lost me). Please read Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? . When code starts out this wrong and misguided, few people can be bothered to take a closer look.

It sounds like your input is a list of names followed by a list of id numbers. If that's the case, wouldn't you really just want this:
int main() {
    std::vector<Student> students;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string name;
        cin >> name;
        Student s;
        s.name = name;
        students.push_back(s);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        students[i].rollno = x;
    }
    return 0;
}

And if you want to optimize further, add a constructor to Student as follows:
class Student {
public:

    ...

    Student(const std::string& n) : name(name), rollno(-1) {
    }

    ...



Such that your first for-loop can be optimized as follows:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    students.emplace_back(Student(name));
}

Then your second loop that adds the roll id number stays the same.

emplace_back(name) is all that's required.

In first code block  students.push_back(s); makes multiple copies of the object Student s; and stores in std::vector<Student> students; if i input 10 different strings and 10 different integers then use
for( auto& i:students){cout<<i.name<<" "<<i.rollno<<endl; } it will print correct result
I want o know how the copies of Student s; are stored in std::vector students;` on memory level

Also I want know what dose the std::vector students;stores, according to what is apparent on surface it seems that the vector is storing the copies of objectsand the vector will be likestd::vector students = { s , s , s , s , s , s , s , s , s , s };` or it will be something different

Second loop can directly do std::cin >> students[i].rollno;.

@shishi - If you simply had vector<shared_ptr<Student>> as your array, all these concerns about making copies just go away. Also, sometimes it's just better to live with the copy overhead than trying to overoptimize every line to avoid it.  YMMV.
